# Adding leaflet.fullscreen plugin for QGIS2WEB

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis2web, plugins

What I have done after export of the qgis2web leaflet files:

Copied the two css and js files to the folders.

Include the plugin code within the index.html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Control.FullScreen.css" />
<script src="js/Control.FullScreen.js"></script>
```

to the other css/js link files (head/body)

Also insert to the index.html:

```
var map = new L.Map('map', {
  fullscreenControl: true,
  fullscreenControlOptions: {
    position: 'topleft'
  }
});
```

at the end, before

```
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Result: I see the correct leaflet map **without** this plugin.

I have used the code from 
https://github.com/brunob/leaflet.fullscreen

**What is wrong?**

EDIT:
one error:
[image]

The whole code of the index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/L.Control.Locate.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/qgis2web.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet-measure.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Leaflet.Dialog.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Control.FullScreen.css" />
        <style>
        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        </style>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map">
        </div>
        <script src="js/qgis2web_expressions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/leaflet-src.js"></script><script src="js/L.Control.Locate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/leaflet.rotatedMarker.js"></script>
        <script src="js/leaflet.pattern.js"></script>
        <script src="js/leaflet-hash.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Autolinker.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/rbush.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/labelgun.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/labels.js"></script>
        <script src="js/leaflet-measure.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Leaflet.Dialog.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Control.FullScreen.js"></script>
        <script src="data/vomRathausplatz10minzuFu_0.js"></script>
        <script src="data/StraenbahnHaltestellen_1.js"></script>
        <script src="data/Auffhrungsorte_2.js"></script>
        <script src="data/Veranstaltungsortbersicht_3.js"></script>
        <script src="data/Theatergruppen_4.js"></script>

        <script>



        var map = L.map('map', {
            zoomControl:true, maxZoom:18, minZoom:13
        }).fitBounds([[49.4760004288,8.4330598115],[49.4883618774,8.45875065318]]);

        var hash = new L.Hash(map);
        map.attributionControl.addAttribution('<a href="https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web" target="_blank">qgis2web</a>');
        L.control.locate().addTo(map);
        var measureControl = new L.Control.Measure({
            primaryLengthUnit: 'meters',
            secondaryLengthUnit: 'kilometers',
            primaryAreaUnit: 'sqmeters',
            secondaryAreaUnit: 'hectares'
        });



        measureControl.addTo(map);
        var bounds_group = new L.featureGroup([]);
        var basemap0 = L.tileLayer('http://a.tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>,<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash;Map data: &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>contributors,<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>',
            maxZoom: 18
        });





        basemap0.addTo(map);
        function setBounds() {
        }
        function pop_vomRathausplatz10minzuFu_0(feature, layer) {
        }

        function style_vomRathausplatz10minzuFu_0_0() {
            return {
                pane: 'pane_vomRathausplatz10minzuFu_0',
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'rgba(199,77,39,0.12)',
                dashArray: '',
                lineCap: 'butt',
                lineJoin: 'miter',
                weight: 8.0, 
                fill: true,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                fillColor: 'rgba(0,2,1,0.12)',
            }
        }
        map.createPane('pane_vomRathausplatz10minzuFu_0');
        map.getPane('pane_vomRathausplatz10minzuFu_0').style.zIndex = 400;
        map.getPane('pane_vomRathausplatz10minzuFu_0').style['mix-blend-mode'] = 'normal';
        var layer_vomRathausplatz10minzuFu_0 = new L.geoJson(json_vomRathausplatz10minzuFu_0, {
            attribution: '<a href=""></a>',
            pane: 'pane_vomRathausplatz10minzuFu_0',
            onEachFeature: pop_vomRathausplatz10minzuFu_0,
            style: style_vomRathausplatz10minzuFu_0_0,
        });
        bounds_group.addLayer(layer_vomRathausplatz10minzuFu_0);
        function pop_StraenbahnHaltestellen_1(feature, layer) {
            var popupContent = '<table>\
                    <tr>\
                        <td colspan="2">' + (feature.properties['name'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['name'])) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                    <tr>\
                        <td colspan="2">' + (feature.properties['wheelchair'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['wheelchair'])) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                </table>';
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {maxHeight: 400});
        }

        function style_StraenbahnHaltestellen_1_0() {
            return {
                pane: 'pane_StraenbahnHaltestellen_1',
        rotationAngle: 0.0,
        rotationOrigin: 'center center',
        icon: L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'markers/34-Hotel-Icon-Near-Transit-Stop.svg',
            iconSize: [28.88, 28.88]
        }),
            }
        }
        map.createPane('pane_StraenbahnHaltestellen_1');
        map.getPane('pane_StraenbahnHaltestellen_1').style.zIndex = 401;
        map.getPane('pane_StraenbahnHaltestellen_1').style['mix-blend-mode'] = 'normal';
        var layer_StraenbahnHaltestellen_1 = new L.geoJson(json_StraenbahnHaltestellen_1, {
            attribution: '<a href=""></a>',
            pane: 'pane_StraenbahnHaltestellen_1',
            onEachFeature: pop_StraenbahnHaltestellen_1,
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                var context = {
                    feature: feature,
                    variables: {}
                };
                return L.marker(latlng, style_StraenbahnHaltestellen_1_0(feature));
            },
        });
        bounds_group.addLayer(layer_StraenbahnHaltestellen_1);
        map.addLayer(layer_StraenbahnHaltestellen_1);
        function pop_Auffhrungsorte_2(feature, layer) {
            var popupContent = '<table>\
                    <tr>\
                        <td colspan="2">' + (feature.properties['fid'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['fid'])) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                    <tr>\
                        <td colspan="2">' + (feature.properties['Platz/Ort'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['Platz/Ort'])) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                    <tr>\
                        <td colspan="2">' + (feature.properties['Aufführung'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['Aufführung'])) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                    <tr>\
                        <td colspan="2">' + (feature.properties['Veranstalt'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['Veranstalt'])) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                </table>';
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {maxHeight: 400});
        }

        function style_Auffhrungsorte_2_0() {
            return {
                pane: 'pane_Auffhrungsorte_2',
                radius: 0.0,
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'rgba(0,0,0,1.0)',
                dashArray: '',
                lineCap: 'butt',
                lineJoin: 'miter',
                weight: 1,
                fill: true,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                fillColor: 'rgba(180,145,255,1.0)',
            }
        }
        map.createPane('pane_Auffhrungsorte_2');
        map.getPane('pane_Auffhrungsorte_2').style.zIndex = 402;
        map.getPane('pane_Auffhrungsorte_2').style['mix-blend-mode'] = 'normal';
        var layer_Auffhrungsorte_2 = new L.geoJson(json_Auffhrungsorte_2, {
            attribution: '<a href=""></a>',
            pane: 'pane_Auffhrungsorte_2',
            onEachFeature: pop_Auffhrungsorte_2,
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                var context = {
                    feature: feature,
                    variables: {}
                };
                return L.circleMarker(latlng, style_Auffhrungsorte_2_0(feature));
            },
        });
        bounds_group.addLayer(layer_Auffhrungsorte_2);
        map.addLayer(layer_Auffhrungsorte_2);
        function pop_Veranstaltungsortbersicht_3(feature, layer) {
            var popupContent = '<table>\
                    <tr>\
                        <td colspan="2"><strong>Platz/Ort (real)</strong><br />' + (feature.properties['Platz/Ort (real)'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['Platz/Ort (real)'])) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                    <tr>\
                        <td colspan="2"><strong>Aufführungs-Platzname</strong><br />' + (feature.properties['Aufführungs-Platzname'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['Aufführungs-Platzname'])) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                    <tr>\
                        <td colspan="2"><strong>Veranstaltungen Tag/Uhrzeit/Theatergruppe</strong><br />' + (feature.properties['Veranstaltungen Tag/Uhrzeit/Theatergruppe'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['Veranstaltungen Tag/Uhrzeit/Theatergruppe'])) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                </table>';
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {maxHeight: 400});
        }

        function style_Veranstaltungsortbersicht_3_0() {
            return {
                pane: 'pane_Veranstaltungsortbersicht_3',
                stroke: false, 
                fill: true,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                fillColor: 'rgba(241,207,55,0.54)',
            }
        }
        map.createPane('pane_Veranstaltungsortbersicht_3');
        map.getPane('pane_Veranstaltungsortbersicht_3').style.zIndex = 403;
        map.getPane('pane_Veranstaltungsortbersicht_3').style['mix-blend-mode'] = 'normal';
        var layer_Veranstaltungsortbersicht_3 = new L.geoJson(json_Veranstaltungsortbersicht_3, {
            attribution: '<a href=""></a>',
            pane: 'pane_Veranstaltungsortbersicht_3',
            onEachFeature: pop_Veranstaltungsortbersicht_3,
            style: style_Veranstaltungsortbersicht_3_0,
        });
        bounds_group.addLayer(layer_Veranstaltungsortbersicht_3);
        map.addLayer(layer_Veranstaltungsortbersicht_3);
        function pop_Theatergruppen_4(feature, layer) {
            var popupContent = '<table>\
                    <tr>\
                        <td colspan="2">' + (feature.properties['fid'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['fid'])) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                    <tr>\
                        <td colspan="2">' + (feature.properties['Theatergruppe'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['Theatergruppe'])) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                    <tr>\
                        <td colspan="2">' + (feature.properties['Veranstaltungsplatz'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['Veranstaltungsplatz'])) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                </table>';
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {maxHeight: 400});
        }

        function style_Theatergruppen_4_0(feature) {
            switch(String(feature.properties['Veranstaltungsplatz'])) {
                case 'Großes Theater':
                    return {
                pane: 'pane_Theatergruppen_4',
        rotationAngle: 0.0,
        rotationOrigin: 'center center',
        icon: L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'markers/Theatermaske blau.svg',
            iconSize: [11.4, 11.4]
        }),
            }
                    break;
                case 'Tanzboden':
                    return {
                pane: 'pane_Theatergruppen_4',
        rotationAngle: 0.0,
        rotationOrigin: 'center center',
        icon: L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'markers/Theatermaske rot.svg',
            iconSize: [38.0, 38.0]
        }),
            }
                    break;
                case 'Verrückte Fahrbahn':
                    return {
                pane: 'pane_Theatergruppen_4',
        rotationAngle: 0.0,
        rotationOrigin: 'center center',
        icon: L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'markers/Theatermaske.svg',
            iconSize: [38.0, 38.0]
        }),
            }
                    break;
                case 'mehrere Theatergruppen':
                    return {
                pane: 'pane_Theatergruppen_4',
        rotationAngle: 0.0,
        rotationOrigin: 'center center',
        icon: L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'markers/city_large.svg',
            iconSize: [30.4, 30.4]
        }),
            }
                    break;
            }
        }
        map.createPane('pane_Theatergruppen_4');
        map.getPane('pane_Theatergruppen_4').style.zIndex = 404;
        map.getPane('pane_Theatergruppen_4').style['mix-blend-mode'] = 'normal';
        var layer_Theatergruppen_4 = new L.geoJson(json_Theatergruppen_4, {
            attribution: '<a href=""></a>',
            pane: 'pane_Theatergruppen_4',
            onEachFeature: pop_Theatergruppen_4,
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                var context = {
                    feature: feature,
                    variables: {}
                };
                return L.marker(latlng, style_Theatergruppen_4_0(feature));
            },
        });
        bounds_group.addLayer(layer_Theatergruppen_4);
        map.addLayer(layer_Theatergruppen_4);
        var baseMaps = {};
        L.control.layers(baseMaps,{'Theatergruppen<br /><table><tr><td style="text-align: center;"><img src="legend/Theatergruppen_4_GroesTheater0.png" /></td><td>Großes Theater</td></tr><tr><td style="text-align: center;"><img src="legend/Theatergruppen_4_Tanzboden1.png" /></td><td>Tanzboden</td></tr><tr><td style="text-align: center;"><img src="legend/Theatergruppen_4_VerrckteFahrbahn2.png" /></td><td>Verrückte Fahrbahn</td></tr><tr><td style="text-align: center;"><img src="legend/Theatergruppen_4_mehrereTheatergruppen3.png" /></td><td>mehrere Theatergruppen</td></tr></table>': layer_Theatergruppen_4,'<img src="legend/Veranstaltungsortbersicht_3.png" /> Veranstaltungsort Übersicht': layer_Veranstaltungsortbersicht_3,'<img src="legend/Auffhrungsorte_2.png" /> Aufführungsorte': layer_Auffhrungsorte_2,'<img src="legend/StraenbahnHaltestellen_1.png" /> Straßenbahn Haltestellen': layer_StraenbahnHaltestellen_1,'<img src="legend/vomRathausplatz10minzuFu_0.png" /> vom Rathausplatz 10min zu Fuß': layer_vomRathausplatz10minzuFu_0,},{collapsed:false}).addTo(map);
        setBounds();
        var i = 0;
        layer_Auffhrungsorte_2.eachLayer(function(layer) {
            var context = {
                feature: layer.feature,
                variables: {}
            };
            layer.bindTooltip((layer.feature.properties['Aufführung'] !== null?String('<div style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 11pt; background-color: #000201; border: 0px solid #808080; padding: 0px 0px; font-family: \'MS Shell Dlg 2\', sans-serif;">' + layer.feature.properties['Aufführung']) + '</div>':''), {permanent: true, offset: [-0, -16], className: 'css_Auffhrungsorte_2'});
            labels.push(layer);
            totalMarkers += 1;
              layer.added = true;
              addLabel(layer, i);
              i++;
        });
        resetLabels([layer_Auffhrungsorte_2]);
        map.on("zoomend", function(){
            resetLabels([layer_Auffhrungsorte_2]);
        });
        map.on("layeradd", function(){
            resetLabels([layer_Auffhrungsorte_2]);
        });
        map.on("layerremove", function(){
            resetLabels([layer_Auffhrungsorte_2]);
        });


        var dialog = L.control.dialog({size: [200, 150]})
          .setContent("<p>Schön, dass du hier bist!</p>")
          .addTo(map);

          var map = new L.Map('map', {
  fullscreenControl: true,
  fullscreenControlOptions: {
    position: 'topleft'
  }
});

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code it's impossible to say what is wrong. You write that you inserted code to create the map. How was it created before?

Comment: Above the whole code.
The code was created from the qgis2web plugin. After export I can change the code. 
The plugin create a fully website as a leaflet map and the qgis layers.

Comment: Please check your browser's Developer Console for any error messages.

Comment: One error. See above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error tells you, you are trying to initialize map twice.

Remove your second initialization

```
var map = new L.Map('map', {
  fullscreenControl: true,
  fullscreenControlOptions: {
    position: 'topleft'
  }
});
```

and modify original map initialization with `Lefalet.fullscreen` plugin options:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  zoomControl: true,
  maxZoom: 18,
  minZoom: 13,
  fullscreenControl: true,
  fullscreenControlOptions: {
    position: 'topleft'
  }
}).fitBounds([[49.4760004288,8.4330598115],[49.4883618774,8.45875065318]]);
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.
Only thing: I have the button, but without the graphic in it.
I have png graphic symbols and I have an image folder within the css folder with this copied symbols, but I can not see them.

Comment: Have found the solution:
I have insert this code in my index.html:

<style type="text/css">
  
  .fullscreen-icon { background-image: url(icon-fullscreen.png); }
  .leaflet-retina .fullscreen-icon { background-image: url(icon-fullscreen-2x.png); background-size: 26px 26px; }
 </style>